# howto to get a real time rss notification

Tags: python, rss

Im trying to build a python script that will process a RSS feed and will run every time a new post is being uploaded. Is there a better way to do this than polling the feed for updates?

Thanks

Comment: other than black magic, no. - but you can poll intelligently, by first requesting to know if there are any updates to the feed since your last check. instead of simply retrieving the full feed each time.

Comment: http://packages.python.org/feedparser/http-etag.html#etag-and-last-modified-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the RSS feed publisher implementing any kind of publishing protocol you can subscribe to?

You can read up on [PubSubHubbub](https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/)

```
Parties (servers) speaking the PubSubHubbub protocol can get near-instant notifications (via webhook callbacks) when a topic (feed URL) they're interested in is updated.
```

Comment: no, sadly nothing but the RSS feed itself. I noticed PubSubHubbub but its not in use here.

Comment: Have you looked at Yahoo pipes? http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Depending on what you intend to do, might solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer here is it depends.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949755/1199721) post for a proper explanation. I also suggest looking at [PubSubHubbub](https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) which is mentioned in my first link:

> A simple, open, server-to-server web-hook-based pubsub (publish/subscribe) protocol as an extension to Atom and RSS.
>
> Parties (servers) speaking the PubSubHubbub protocol can get near-instant notifications (via webhook callbacks) when a topic (feed URL) they're interested in is updated.