# Parsing URLs from RSS-feed

Tags: php, parsing, laravel, rss, simplepie

My web application parses URLs from certain RSS-feeds. I'm using Simple Pie for this purpose. Parsing is working perfectly. All parsed URLs are stored in database and I'm generating a webpage from this URL-table.

How can I check if RSS-feed have a new URL to offer which is not yet brought to my database? At the moment I check the whole URL-table through and compare the first URLs from the feed, but I doubt this would be most efficient way of handling this...

Comment: You could make the url column unique and just try to insert the *new* url. Then if you catch an error that it already exists, it exists. I'm not certain this is best practice but it should work.

Comment: You may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949688/how-large-rss-reader-works-netvibes-google-reader) and its response :)