# Feedly uses SuperFeeder (Pubsubhubbub). How does feedly allow users to subscribe to RSS feed which is not published using pubsubhubbub?

Tags: rss, feed, publish-subscribe, websub

As far as I know, in order to get RSS in real time (i.e be pubsubhubbub subscriber) , the one who generates the RSS feed, must be a pubsubhubbub publisher, which means the RSS feed must include a  tag which includes the HUB address.

However, there are lots of RSS feeds (published using RSS 2.0 only and not pubsubhubbub) which I can subscribe to via Feedly.

How is it possible?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, Feedly does use PubSubHubbub, thru Superfeedr (and other hubs, such as Google's or Wordpress).

Fir the feeds which do not support PubSubHubbub, Feedly polls feeds at regular intervals. You may want to check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949688/how-large-rss-reader-works-netvibes-google-reader) for more details.

Also, please note that Superfeedr can also [be used as a "default hub"](https://superfeedr.com/subscriber/) which works even for feeds which do not support PubSubHubbub.

Comment: Hi, if the feed does not support pubsubhubbub, will superfeeder provide it in real time, or will it just check the updates on an interval basis and then provide the updated feed?

Comment: It depends on the feed. Superfeedr uses a lot of different mechanism to learn about updates in realtime, but the "worst case" scenario is us polling the feeds at regular intervals.

Comment: What's important is that, for our customers, this should stay behind the scene: we will find the best possible way to send them the data as soon as its been updated, for any feed.